# How to make high poly and keep smooth from low poly?

Tags: edges, remesh

So I have created low poly model and want make high poly model from it. But when I try to use Remesh modifier, the edges become visible on the high poly model. Is there any way to make high poly and keep smooth from the low poly?

[image]

Comment: Enable the Smooth Shading checkbox in the modifier

Comment: why not use catmull clark instead of remesh?

Comment: You want to use a Subdivision modifier on it, not a remesh one.